# Как правильно реализовывать модель MVP?

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

Пытаюсь разобраться с тем, как улучшить работу с WinForms и разделить логику и представление. Наткнулся на шаблон MVP с краткими примерами и пытаюсь понять как им пользоваться. На данный момент имею следующий код, но мне кажется я делаю что-то не так. К тому же у меня в эту модель совсем не укладывается реализация многопоточности. Отсюда вопрос, как правильно реализовать шаблон проектирования MVP в WinForms?

**View реализация**

```
interface ICustomer
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    string SurName { get; set; }
    string Address { get; set; }
    string Code { get; set; }

    event Action Search;
    event Action Cancel;
}

public partial class Customer : Form, ICustomer
{
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return lblFirstName.Text; }
        set { lblFirstName.Text = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lblLastName.Text; }
        set { lblLastName.Text = value; }
    }

    public string SurName
    {
        get { return lblSurname.Text; }
        set { lblSurname.Text = value; }
    }

    public string Address
    {
        get { return lblAddress.Text; }
        set { lblAddress.Text = value; }
    }

    public string Code
    {
        get { return txtCode.Text; }
        set { txtCode.Text = value; }
    }

    public event Action Search;
    public event Action Cancel;

    public Customer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Search();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cancel();
    }
}
```

**Presenter реализация**

```
class CustomerPresenter 
{
    public ICustomer View;
    public ICustomerModel Model;

    public CustomerPresenter(ICustomer view, ICustomerModel model)
    {
        View = view;
        Model = model;

        View.Search += View_Search;
        View.Cancel += View_Cancel;
    }

    private void View_Search()
    {
        new Task(() => {
            View.FirstName = "Alex Krass";
        }).Start();
    }

    private void View_Cancel()
    {

    }
}
```

**Модель и вызов**

Модель у меня пока пустая, как я понимаю с ней проблем не должно быть, вызов всего этого безобразия через Unity IoC.

```
class UnityIoC
{
    private static UnityContainer unityContainer;

    public static UnityContainer Instance 
    {
        get
        {
            if (unityContainer == null) CreateContainer();
            return unityContainer;
        }
    }

    private static void CreateContainer()
    {
        unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
        unityContainer.RegisterType<ICustomer, Customer>();
        unityContainer.RegisterType<ICustomerModel, CustomerModel>();
    }
} 

static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    ApplicationContext context = new ApplicationContext()
    {
        MainForm = UnityIoC.Instance.Resolve<CustomerPresenter>().View as Form
    };
    context.MainForm.Show();

    Application.Run(context);
}
```

Ну соответственно при нажатии на кнопку Search я не могу обновить UI, неужели придется в Presenter пробрасывать сам TextBox в ICustomer и вызывать BeginInvoke? Или я просто чего-то недопонимаю в реализации MVP?

**UPD:**

Вопрос с обновлением UI без его блокирования вроде решился через использование таймера, когда информацию надо забирать по мере выполнения `Task` и через `TaskScheduler`, когда надо обновлять после выполнения `Task`.

```
**Вариант 1**

timer = new Timer() { Interval = 1000 };
timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
timer.Start();

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateView();
}

**Вариант 2**
task = new Task(new Action(UpdateModel));
task.ContinueWith(new Action<Task>(UpdateView), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
task.Start();


private void UpdateView(Task task = null)
{
    view.SomeVal = SomeVal;
    view.SomeValNext = SomeValNext;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопросы по интерпретации и реализации паттернов проектирования почти всегда холиварные, поэтому сразу предупреждаю, что все что написано ниже - это мое личное видение основанное на моих же логике, понимании и практике использования WinForms. Про еще один вариант интерпретации и реализации MVP можно почитать в [**статье на хабре**](https://habrahabr.ru/post/211899/)

По аналогии с биологией начнем с простейших одноклеточных (одно-оконных) приложений содержащих только простые контролы (кнопки, картинки, текстовые поля со вводом или без).

**1. Одноклеточные**

Определимся с компонентами паттерна и тем, какие элементы приложения к ним относятся.

- **M** - Model - отдельный класс инкапсулирующий работу с данными. Все операции над данными производятся только в нем. Если рассматривать модель под микроскопом, то в ней можно рассмотреть много-поточную или асинхронную обработку тяжелых вычислений, обращения к сервисам и базам данных и прочие слои свойственные моделям.
- **V** - View - визуальное представление данных модели. Сюда можно отнести все контролы нашей, пока единственной, формы, которые собственно отображают нашу модель с выбранного ракурса.
- **P** - Presenter - не буду выдумывать специальный перевод, остановимся на длинном но более-менее точном определении - компонент, который отвечает за получение данных из модели и знает как и когда их нужно отображать, а также обрабатывает пользовательский ввод, дергает модель за соответствующие методы и обрабатывает события модели.

В случае простейших, презентером будет выступать класс формы, в логике которого мы и организуем передачу данных из модели в контролы для представления данных и обработку событий контролов, для передачи в модель действий пользователя.

**2. Многоклеточные**

Когда окон становится больше одного или появляются сложные контролы, предыдущая модель приложения все еще имеет право на существование, но работать с ней становится неудобно.

Добавим класс-презентер, для которого в качестве представления будут выступать наши одноклеточные описанные выше. Его главная задача - передать частным перезентерам нужный кусочек модели для работы, агрегировать события от них и передавать эти события в нужном порядке и количестве в модель, а также маршрутизировать события модели к частным презентерам. Для частных презентеров - общий будет выступать в роли модели. Также в нем можно реализовать много-поточное/асинхронное обращение к модели, т.к. он связан только с моделью и подчиненными презентерами, а не элементами UI, за которые отвечают частные презентеры.

Таким образом получается что наше приложение состоит из множества простых, относительно самостоятельных фрагментов, под руководством старшего презентера, обеспечивающего их согласованную работу.

**3. Меняем паттерн**

Приложение растет и усложняется и в определенный момент даже многоклеточная модель становится неудобной.

Тут самое время вспомнить, что WinForms поддерживает DataBinding. А в связи с этим можно немного поменять шаблон. В сети он часто упоминается как **MVPVM**.

Тут появляется новый компонент - **VM** - view-model, и роль презентера немного меняется. VM - по сути, срез модели для отображения. В задачи презентера теперь не будет входить передача данных в подчиненные вьюхи, а только создание биндингов к нужным VM, привязка биндингов к вьюхам и обработка событий. И мы в принципе можем отказаться от общего презентера, т.к. при создании очередного контрола можно просто передавать в него нужную VM, а остальное он сделает сам. Правда в сложных случаях нам все еще будет нужен агрегатор для событий, особенно если события от разных контролов взаимосвязаны или конфиликтуют между собой.

Эта модель позволяет наиболее гибкое расширение функционала и массштабирование приложения.

**4. Заключение**

Несмотря на то, что я рассматривал каждую модель по отдельности, на самом деле они плавно вытекают одна из другой по мере усложнения приложения и на практике в чистом виде ни одна из рассмотренных моделей практически не встречается и даже простое с виду приложение может требовать сложных комбинированных решений и наоборот. Просто следуйте логике, здравому смыслу и принципу - "проще - лучше".

> Ну соответственно при нажатии на кнопку Search я не могу обновить UI,
>   неужели придется в Presenter пробрасывать сам TextBox в ICustomer и
>   вызывать BeginInvoke? Или я просто чего-то недопонимаю в реализации
>   MVP?

По предложенным мной вариантам, вы используете второй вариант, и единственно чего в нем не хватает - это события в `CustomerPresenter` о том что поиск завершен и можно забирать данные для отображения, на которое сможет подписаться форма. Или определить в `ICustomer` и реализовать в форме `Customer` метод `DataUpdate` (или переопределить метод Control.Update формы) и вызывать его из `CustomerPresenter`когда поиск завершен и к результатам можно получить доступ из основного потока.

краткий алгоритм:

- кнопкой (или другим действием) на форме `Customer` передаем запрос на поиск в `CustomerPresenter`.
- `CustomerPresenter` передает запрос в модель
- модель активирует поиск отдельным потоком. Компоненты основного потока с этого момента свободны для другой полезной работы.
- посик завершен, результаты загружены в модель. Модель активирует событие о том, что поиск завершен.
- `CustomerPresenter` получает событие о завершении поиска, получает результаты поиска из модели и:

  1. вызывает метод UpdateData (примерное название) у формы и передает результаты поиска в параметрах.
  2. активирует событие завершения длительной операции
- `Customer`, получает результаты поиска у `CustomerPresenter`, как именно зависит от предыдущего пункта, и отображает их.

Простоя в работе интерфейса во время поиска нет.

Можно и по имеющемуся сценарию:

- кнопкой (или другим действием) на форме `Customer` передаем запрос на поиск в `CustomerPresenter`.
- `CustomerPresenter` в отдельном потоке вызывает метод поиска в модели. Компоненты основного потока с этого момента свободны для другой полезной работы.
- После завершения в потоке поиска с помощью Invoke:

  1. вызываем метод UpdateData (примерное название) у формы и передает результаты поиска в параметрах.
  2. активируем событие завершения длительной операции
- `Customer`, получает результаты поиска у `CustomerPresenter`, как именно зависит от предыдущего пункта, и отображает их.

Еще можно завернуть длинный поиск в асинхронный метод, и уже внутри ожидать завершения потока поиска без подвешивания интерфейса, но этот вариант я только в теории представляю, руками не делал.

Comment: Спасибо. Да, у меня второй вариант, т.к. первый уже трудно поддерживать. На данный момент у меня операция по поиску данных достаточно долгая и основной поток я не могу блокировать на удержание. События из самого `Task` тоже пробросить не получается, оно как я понимаю будет проброшено не в основной поток. Пока пришел к решению через таймер на условие `if (task.IsCompleted == true) { UpdateView(); }`, но хотелось бы `Callback` какой-нить. В любом случае я как обычно жду до конца недели перед закрытием, мало ли кто-то еще что-нибудь ответит.