# Паттерн MVP для Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

У меня есть небольшой проект, который я хочу переписать, используя паттерн MVP. Проект на платформе Windows Forms. 
Я изучила некоторую литературу, я понимаю организацию классов на объясняемых примерах, но применить к своей задаче не могу, получается какая-то каша. 
Растолкуйте пожалуйста, как правильно организовать классы для моего случая с задачей.
Цель проекта такова: на вход подается несколько файлов или папка с файлами (например пользователь выбирает файлы с помощью диалога OpenFiles/OpenFolder), далее мне необходимо обработать каждый файл и найти в каждом из них некоторые ошибки. После обработки мне необходимо вывести список ошибок в разрезе файлов.

Я организовала следующие классы: View, Presenter и Model.
View это форма, на ней я набросала некоторый интерфейс, после выбора файлов, я передаю массив строк с путями к выбранным файлам в Presenter, из Presenter вызываю метод в Model, который в цикле прогоняет каждый файл в методе проверки и возвращаю массив ошибок.
Сейчас у меня все равно логика не разделена, в View выполняется работа с визуальными компонентами. Я в источниках почитала, что в View минимум операций должно происходить.

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот [видео урок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6RNy3rPZpg&list=PLWCoo5SF-qAMDIAqikhB2hvIytrMiR5TC&index=8). очень просто и доходчиво на русском языке, на конкретном простом примере объясняется MVP применительно к  Windows Forms. Да, и в целом канал очень хороший и полезный.

Comment: Посмотрите тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572971/198316, возможно дубль