# Эталонная реализация MVP в WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, шаблоны-проектирования, mvp

Хочу понять MVP паттерн на практике, но, кажется, не все понимаю правильно, поэтому простой вопрос: на форме есть кнопка и лейбл, так же есть некая переменная-счетчик. При нажатии кнопки счетчик должен увеличиваться на 1, а текст надписи должен меняться на значение счетчика. Моя реализация выглядит так:

Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Model _model;
        View _view;
        Presenter _presenter;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _model = new Model();
            _view = new View(label1);
            _presenter = new Presenter(_view, _model);
            button1.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                _view.RefreshView();
            };
        }
    }
```

Model

```
class Model
    {
        private int count = 0;

        public void IncCount()
        {
            count++;
        }

        public int GetCount()
        {
            return count;
        }
    }
```

View

```
delegate void ViewChanged();

    class View
    {
        public event ViewChanged OnViewChanged;
        private Label _label;

        public View(Label label)
        {
            _label = label;
        }

        public void RefreshView()
        {
            OnViewChanged();
        }

        public void ChangeLabel(string data)
        {
            _label.Text = data;
        }
    }
```

Presenter

```
class Presenter
    {
        View _view;
        Model _model;

        public Presenter(View view, Model model)
        {
            _view = view;
            _view.OnViewChanged += _view_OnViewChanged;
            _model = model;
        }

        private void _view_OnViewChanged()
        {
            _model.IncCount();
            _view.ChangeLabel(_model.GetCount().ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: не существует "эталонных реализаций" паттернов, потому что паттерн - это **концепция** подхода к решению некоторого класса задач, а не руководство к действию. По вашему варианту - я не понимаю зачем вам отдельный класс View, эти обязанности прекрасно выполняют базовые контролы или форма, там уже есть все необходимое. Получается просто лишняя прослойка, которая ни на что не влияет, кроме усложнения кода. Некоторые мои мысли и рассуждения на эту тему можете почитать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572971/198316)

Comment: Я понимаю, что для данной задачи MVP избыточен, но хотелось понять на самом примитивном примере без сотен строк кода. Спасибо за ссылку, прочту

Comment: Думаю, одной эталонной реализации быть не может. Например, представление может быть полностью пассивным, а может и как-то реагировать на ввод. Посмотреть разновидности можно, в частности, у Мартина Фаулера: [MVP](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html#Model-view-presentermvp) (и там по ссылкам смотрите) или [здесь](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/) справа список Presentation Patterns.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за ссылки. Можете, пожалуйста, написать ответ, тк комментарий выбрать решением нельзя